# Lenovo B40-80 touchpad not working

Tags: 17.10, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

Ubuntu version: 17.10

Touchpad was working fine earlier but I needed to get my display replaced and since the laptop came after repair touchpad is not working in Ubuntu however it is working fine in windows10 (I'm using dual boot).

I tried some solutions posted online but couldn't get it to work.

I found that it shows up when I run this command `less /proc/bus/input/devices` and following comes up along with some other devices.

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

But the it does not come when I run `xinput`. Following is the result of this command.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.